# Server MyEclipse Tomcat v7.0 was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor

Tags: tomcat, server, myeclipse

I'm keep getting this error:
"Server MyEclipse Tomcat v7.0 was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor."
I already tried to increase the timeout, but it didn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you give almost no details of your setup, I'm not sure if this applies to you but a problem like this was reported on the MyEclipse forums. It was to do with port forwarding on OS X Yosemite. If this is your situation, check out [that forum topic](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/myeclipse-2015-ci-started-tomcat-is-not-recognised-yosemite/) for a solution (at the end).

If this isn't your situation, then you should add as much detail as possible about the problem (at least: the release of the MyEclipse, the operating system and version, the version of Tomcat, whether Tomcat does start but isn't detected as started, and whether this is something that has just started happening after something changed in your setup).